# Pass Callback Function to Custom View in Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-xml, android-custom-attributes

I have a custom view in my android project, `MyCustomView`.

With a built-in view like button, I can use the data binding library to pass a callback function to the button:

```xml
<Button
    ...
    android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.donePressed()}" />
```

How can I pass a callback function which I can access in the `MyCustomView` class through the XML?

I want it to look something like this:

```xml
<MyCustomView app:onFinish="@{() -> viewModel.finish()}" />
```

Then in the `MyCustomView` class (extending `LinearLayout`) I need to call the `onFinish` variable.

Thank you for any ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer: This is actually done automatically by Android.

If I add a *public* setter to my `MyCustomView` class like this:

```kotlin
public fun setOnFinish(callback: () -> Unit) {
    ...
}
```

Then Android will automatically generate the `app:onFinish` attribute (without the `set` part of the name):

```xml
<MyCustomView app:onFinish="@{() -> viewModel.finish()}" />
```

Then, the function I defined is called after the constructor of the custom view.

If you need further customisation you can also use a Binding Adapter: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters